# Link with a image and gestureDetector

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making a app for fun and to learn. When I added interactivity by first time, I found a error by adding gesturedetector. Gesture detector has to open a new function which is a window with more things. The gesture detector is inside a column, inside a container inside a ListView (The order is LsitView->Container->GestureDetector)

```
class _HomePageUserState extends State<HomePageUser> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      //itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: Container (
            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            alignment:Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget> [
                  Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Nombre del comercio'),),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10), child: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg', 
                        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                        height: 200,),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VistaUsuario()),
                          );
                        },
                        onLongPress: () {},
                      ),
                    ), 
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Estrellas'),),
                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), child: Text('Precio (rango)'),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Se produjo una excepción. FlutterError (Vertical viewport was given unbounded height. Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget. If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.)
```

Comment: Can you provide full code, at least from Column

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your GestureDetector in **SingleChildScrollView**  .this will scroll the page.

```
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test page'),
      ),
      body:SingleChildScrollView(

        child:Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  height: 200,),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VistaUsuario()),
                  );
                },
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Another Solution is to use **Expanded** widget.This will expand the image to take rest of the page

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test page'),
      ),
      body:Center(

        child:Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 0,
              ),
              
              Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Image.network('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg/800px-Spaghetti_Bolognese_mit_Parmesan_oder_Grana_Padano.jpg',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      height: 200,),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const VistaUsuario()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
              
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
```